# How to add Headers in AWS (ada web server)?

Tags: cors, ada

I have been trying to add Headers (specifically for CORS) to my server response for hours now, but I cant find a way in ada with AWS. Can someone help me? ( So far I have found only ways to add the Headers to the Client, but not as a Server Response)

Please ignore that the code is a bit messy, this is my first real project in Ada and I am just trying things out.

```
with AWS.Client;
with AWS.Response;
with AWS.Server;
with AWS.Server.Status;
with AWS.Status;
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with AWS.Headers;

procedure aws_test is:

   WS      : AWS.Server.HTTP;
   Headers : AWS.Headers.List;

   function HW_CB (Request : in AWS.Status.Data) return AWS.Response.Data is
      URI : constant String := AWS.Status.URI (Request);

      Test_Data : AWS.Response.Data :=
        AWS.Client.Get (URL => "http://192.168.190.129");

      Test_String   : constant String := AWS.Response.Message_Body (Test_Data);
      para          : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
      test          : Integer         := 1;
      response_data : AWS.Response.Data;

    begin

      AWS.Headers.Add
        (Table => Headers, Name => "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
         Value => "*");
      -- Allow common methods
      AWS.Headers.Add
        (Table => Headers, Name => "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
         Value => "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");

      -- Allow all headers requested in the actual request
      AWS.Headers.Add
        (Table => Headers, Name => "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
         Value => "*");

      -- Set max age to 86400 seconds (24 hours)
      AWS.Headers.Add
        (Table => Headers, Name => "Access-Control-Max-Age", Value => "86400");

      if URI = "/api/login" then
         -- ADD HERE
         test := test + 1;
         para := AWS.Status.Binary_Data (Request);

         Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_String (para));
         -- Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Test_String);

         response_data := AWS.Response.Build ("text/html", "<p>Hello world !");
         AWS.Response.Set.Add_Header
           (response_data, Name => "Access-Control-Max-Age", Value => "86400");
         return response_data;
      else
         return AWS.Response.Build ("text/html", "<p>Hum...");
      end if;
    end HW_CB;

    begin
     AWS.Server.Start
      (WS, "Hotel AI", Callback => HW_CB'Unrestricted_Access, Port => 8_080);
     delay 20.0;
     AWS.Server.Shutdown (WS);
     while AWS.Server.Status.Is_Shutdown (WS) = False loop
      delay 5.0;
     end loop;
    end aws_test;
```

I just would like to add Headers so I dont get CORS flagged in Javascript. Thank you very much for your Help ( I am a bit struggling to find good resources on these topics in the web )

I have already tried several possible ways (as well with the help of AI etc.), bu tI couldn't even really find good examples on Github or in the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, have you tried sending the header before the response?

Try replacing:

```
return AWS.Response.Build ("text/html", "<p>Hum...");
```

with:

```
return Result : AWS.Response.Data := AWS.Response.Build ("text/html", "<p>Hum...") do
   AWS.Headers.Send_Header(
        Socket    => SOCKET,
        Headers   => HEADERS
      );
end return;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I really appreciate it:)

I am currently not at my working station, but I was able to look a bit into. 
I thought about Send_Header as well, but it requires a Socket right - isn't that rather for Clients sending Headers? Or how would you get Socket as a Server? 

(I will continue debugging more once I am at home again)


Edit: Looks like AWS.Status.Socket is what I am looking for. I will check later today and then let you know.

Comment: This works, but my Headers are at the top of the Header List? Any Ideas on how I can change that? (They are above the Status Code: HTTP/1.1 200 OK)

Comment: @NicolasBachmaier perhaps using the scope? Pull the definition into the declarative region of HW_CB? Or, I suppose you could make HW_CB a generic with Headers as an `in out` object... or perhaps rename what is currently `headers` (say as `common`), then adding that to your local headers?